# R: Replace Entities in CDATA section of XML

Tags: xml, r

I have an XML file like this:

```
<TextBody>
  <![CDATA[First line.&amp;#10;Second line.]]>
</TextBody>
```

I need to extract the information in `CDATA` using `R` package, which means I want

```
First line.\nSecond line.
```

so I tried `XML` package:

```
xmlParse("<TextBody><![CDATA[First line.&amp;#10;Second line.]]></TextBody>",
         replaceEntities=TRUE)
```

Then I'm stuck at this first step because `replaceEntities` option doesn't seem to work here, I still get `&amp;#10;` in the parsed text.

Anyone can show me how to extract the correct text from this XML?

Answer (score 0):

I can't get `replaceEntities` to work either, so you could use gsub.

```
xpathSApply(doc, "//TextBody", function(x) gsub("&amp;#10;", "\n", xmlValue(x) ))
[1] "First line.\nSecond line."
```

Also, adding xmlParse options=NOENT or replaceEntities = TRUE does not change any of the results below.  I always get entity references in CDATA.

```
doc <- xmlParse("<a>test &quot; &apos; &lt; &gt; &amp;</a>")
xpathSApply(doc, "//a", xmlValue)
[1] "test \" ' < > &"

doc <- xmlParse("<a><![CDATA[test &quot; &apos; &lt; &gt; &amp;]]></a>")
xpathSApply(doc, "//a", xmlValue)
[1] "test &quot; &apos; &lt; &gt; &amp;"
```